# How do I see what [object Object] refers to in Chrome Tools?

Tags: javascript

In chrome tools, how can i view what [OBJECT object] represents?  Testing out function context of keyword 'this'

```
 var Calculator = function (eq) {

            // private members...
            var eqCtl = document.getElementById(eq),
                foo = function () { };

            return {
                add: function (x, y) {
                    var val = x + y;
                    eqCtl.innerHTML = val;

                },

                print: function () {
                    console.log("print:  this" + this);
                    this.test(this);
                },

                test: function (obj) {
                    console.log("test: this " + this);
                    console.log("this: obj" + obj);
                }


            }

        };
```

Comment: You inspect it in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert it to a string. `console.log()` it separately:

```
console.log("test: this ", this);
console.log("test: obj ", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple parameters to `console.log` method

```
console.log("this: obj", obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `console.dir` instead. It should be more informative than `console.log` under certain situations.